# Publishing a container app on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-devops, api-gateway, azure-container-instances

I have a nextJS app working in local container. I uploaded the image to Azure and now my application is up from Azure Container Instances.

its listening on port 3000 on http protocol.

I want to utilize Azure https certificate and have site like https://mysitexyz.azurewebsites.net which should point to my container: http://containerip:3000

What Azure resource should i using to achieve that?

Comment: If it is just one container why not use [Azure Web App for containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/#overview)?

Comment: i did, but somehow its not as straighforward as ACI. when i pushed my app listening on http and port 3000 i could make it work and open from outside @PeterBons

Comment: Ah, I forgot. That is correct, only ports 80 and 443 are supported on Azure Web Apps. Is there a requirement to use port 3000? Using Azure Web Apps is the easiest way to go for you.

Comment: yes agreeable @PeterBons. changing app to listen on 443 instead. its NextJS template which by default listens on 3000 port, so the laziness on my part. Changing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can point your custom DNS to an Azure Container Instances: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-custom-dns

EDIT: *.azurewebsites.net is the DNS assigned when you use Azure App Service. You can't use it outside Azure App Service. What you can do, is run Containers on top of it using Azure Web App for Containers.

Comment: how will that help me use the MS's xyz.azurewebiste.net domain along with its free wild card cert? Above seems to give DNS name to containers IP address only which is something i can do otherwise also

Comment: azurewebiste.net is only available for Azure App Service, it won't work for Azure Container Instance.

Comment: yes that's why need to use that instead

Comment: so unless you use Azure App Service, there's no way. You'd better do what the other guy said in the comments, run containers using Azure Web App for Containers, which runs on App Service.